# MySQL Error Handling using the Signal Statements

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE EXCEPTIONHANDLER (IN P_STUDENT_ID INT)

BEGIN
    DECLARE NOTEXISTS INT;

    BEGIN
    SELECT STUDENT_ID INTO NOTEXISTS
    FROM STUDENT 
    WHERE P_STUDENT_ID = STUDENT_ID;
    IF NOTEXISTS != 15
    THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'NO STUDENT_ID FOUND';
    END IF;
    END;

END$

DELIMITER ;
```

Hi. I want to create a stored procedure that shows a message when I put an ID which does not exist in student table. With the code above, when I call the procedure with the ID 15, as I put in the code, I do not get the message because I have ID 15. But when I call the code for the IDs that already exist in the student table, I still get the message. It shows that the code only works for the ID that I entered in the code (like 15). So, how can I make it work for all IDs?

Comment: why not just do select count(*) as n from student where student_id = p_student_id;
if n=0 the ID doesn't exist, if it's 1, the ID exists.

Comment: How should I change the code?

Comment: press backspace till it's all gone, then start typing new shit... :)
sorry for trolling, but give it a try first, come back if you don't succeed.